# wamp server The configuration file contains s syntax error on line 561: Parameter service specifies unknown service

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, wamp

I use only mysql so deleted the `mariadb` folder from `C:\wamp64\bin` dir. Now i can not start wamp server with the following error

```
The configuration file contains s syntax error on line 561: Parameter service specifies unknown service
```

In the wampmanager.ini file line 561 contains the following line

```
Type: servicesubmenu; Caption: "Service administration 'wampmariadb64'"; Service: wampmariadb64; SubMenu: mariadbService
```

I removed that line but whenever i try to start server that line comes back and causes same error. Is there any way to recover this?

Comment: Why do you spring-boot , java tags?

Comment: sorry removed them